# Don't quote some strings with using json.dumps

Tags: python, json

I'm working on a Django wrapper for jqGrid (yes, another one, the existing ones don't fit my needs). In my wrapper I'm generating the Javascript code that initializes the grid. This code looks like this:

```
$('#my-grid').jqGrid({
    "option1": 12,
    "option2": "option",
    "eventHandler": handlerFunction
});
```

Since I'm generating this code in Python, I've created a dictionary like so:

```
options = {"option1": 12, "option2": "option", "eventHandler": "handlerFunction"}
```

I then use `json.dumps` like so:

```
js_code = "${'#my-grid').jqGrid(%s);" % json.dumps(options)
```

The problem is that json.dumps puts quotes around `"handlerFunction"`, which is not what I want. I want `handlerFunction` to be unquoted, so that it is evaluated as a function in JavaScript, and not as a string.

How can I tell `json.dumps` not to quote some of the strings?

Comment: That is *not* valid JSON...

Comment: I have a similar situation, but I don't want to quote integers, which ***is*** valid Jaon. E.g, `{"value" : 4}`, ***NOT***  `{"value" : "4"}` - any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was hoping a custom [`JsonEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) would do the trick, but no - objects returned from encoders pass through the normal encoding sequence, so strings are quoted.

So I had to do something else:

First I defined the following function:

```
def function(name):
    return '@@' + name + '@@'
```

Then I created a JSON encoding function, instead of json.dumps:

```
def my_dumps(obj, *args, **kwargs):
    s = json.dumps(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    s = s.replace('"@@', '')
    s = s.replace('@@"', '')
    return s
```

Now I can create my to-be-jsoned dictionary like this: `{'event': function(handler)}` and it will be encoded properly.

Not pretty, but it works.

Comment: I was looking at your djqgrid project and ran into this problem.  I was working to fix it and saw this question.  Do you plan to put this into github?  It won't be hard for me to add myself but since you already did the work, can you add it to the project?

Comment: This has been included in the github version.

Comment: I see it now.  This is part of the TemplateColumn.  I was using the TextColumn and adding my own formatter when I ran into this issue.

Thanks for sharing this.  It has been a big help in getting jqGrid working with Django.  I'm making some updates to work with Python 3 which I can share if you are interested when I get this all working.

Comment: That would be great, yes.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work. The solution is not to mix logic in Python and JavaScript. Here is one way: move all your JavaScript to template and pass only *data* to it like this:

```
def some_view(...):
    grid_options = {
        "option1": 12,
        "option2": "option",
    }
    return render(request, {'grid_options': json.dumps(grid_options)})
```

In view:

```
var gridOptions = {{ grid_options }};

$('#my-grid').jqGrid($.extend(gridOptions, {
    "eventHandler": handlerFunction
});
```

Comment: That would go around the problem, in cases where this isn't too messy to implement (I have a few such handlers, sometimes they are installed by default without the user being aware of it).

Answer (score 0):

json.dumps can not provide such function, neither does Python, because it's not a valid json string. You should try to unquote it in JS.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @zmbq's answer: `my_dumps` wraps the keys for you.

```
key_wrap_seq = '@@'

def wrap_key(name):
    return key_wrap_seq + name + key_wrap_seq

def wrap_obj_keys(obj):
    if type(obj) is dict:
        return {wrap_key(k): wrap_obj_keys(obj[k]) for k in obj}
    elif type(obj) is list:
        return [wrap_obj_keys(x) for x in obj]
    else:
        return obj

def my_dumps(obj, *args, **kwargs):
    obj_wrapped = wrap_obj_keys(obj)
    s = json.dumps(obj_wrapped, *args, **kwargs)
    s = s.replace('"'+key_wrap_seq, '')
    s = s.replace(key_wrap_seq+'"', '')
    return s
```

Result:

```
>>> obj = {"name": "john", "age": 22}
>>> my_dumps(obj)
... '{name: "john", age: 22}'
```